# Simple blog in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, post, blogs

Achieve connect to the mySQL database and display the entries using this code, The problem is that it only shows one post as I show multiple post or IDs.?

```
<?php 
    $blog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($blog)) {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $category = $row['category'];
    }
?>
    <table>
    <tr><td><?php echo $title; ?></td><td><?php echo $category; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $content; ?></td></tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution would be to just move the last '}' so it's after you print the two rows.
In that way your code would print several lines for several results.
(also make sure you move the <table> and </table> outside so you don't create lots and lots of tables)

Like this:

```
<table>
<?php 
    $blog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($blog)) {
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $category = $row['category'];
     ?>         
    <tr><td><?php echo $title; ?></td><td><?php echo $category; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $content; ?></td></tr>
   <?php        
    }
?>
 </table>
```

Comment: nice loops works but, how i can display individual results/post in separate html page.?

Comment: @classmorri That is a different question to ask in a separate post as the rules of this website say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display the posts in while loop as well. For now title, content and category variables contains just the last row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

with the way you wrote the code, you will only get the last result from your query because you keep on  overwriting your variables inside the while loop... make your table part of the loop